# Why is BIND 9.8.4 using a lot more CPU time than BIND 9.7.0?

Tags: bind

I recently migrated a small DNS setup from one machine to another. The only thing that changed was the version of bind in use:

```
root@old_box:~ $ named -V
BIND 9.7.0-P1 built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-dlz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=no' '--with-dlz-bdb=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS='
```

versus

```
root@new_box:/etc# named -V
BIND 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2'
using OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
using libxml2 version: 2.8.0
```

CPU usage on the old box was between 0% and 5% while now it's more around 10%. These are very unscientific measurements, I know, but I wondered whether this was a common observation.

The behavior is as far as I can see not related to the [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9/+bug/1038199) where BIND cannot create a `managed-keys.bind` file, as the symptom there would be close to 100% CPU usage.

Thanks for any pointers.

[e]: Michael Hampton made a valid comment about the machines themselves. They're both HP Micro Servers with an Athlon II Neo dual core processor at 800MHz. Both are rated at about 2600 bogomips according to `/proc/cpuinfo`, thus I think CPU percentage should be comparable between the two.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing changed, other than the version of bind? You mentioned changing machines, for instance, and that may be important.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have updated the answer with information about the machines. The BIND configuration directory was copied without modification.

Comment: Is it possible that you're doing DNSSEC verification on the new server, but weren't on the old?  You say that the only thing that changed was the bind version - did you actually copy over the same configuration file?

Comment: To be completely honest, I used ``ansible`` to copy the old configuration over the default configuration on the new installation, so it's possible that there are some changes. Sorry for only mentioning this now. Is there a quick way to check if DNSSEC is enabled?

Comment: First of all it's not entirely clear to me what type of queries you are processing? Is this an authoritative-only server or is it dealing with recursion? As for dnssec, `dnssec-enable` and `dnssec-validation` (see http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.8/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#options for details) are relevant settings to look at. Or you could simply try it with eg `dig +dnssec ...`. Regarding that bug with high cpu usage when misconfigured so that the working dir is not writable, it should be easy to verify that the working directory is writable to eliminate that (or check the logs, I imagine).

Comment: Recursing is enabled, DNSSEC validating seems to be deactivated... I've already spent way too much time on this minor issue and I think I'll just accept the situation, many thanks for your comments and hints though!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but instead of a 5% increase in BIND's CPU usage, it was about 10x as much - from about 6% to 19% CPU (on a single core) to around 150% to 200% CPU.

And just as Håkan Lindqvist posted, it was because I had (intentionally, not through some kind of backup procedure) turned on DNSSEC. Because it was recommended that I do so for some unrelated issues.

If your DNS server is using a lot of CPU, you should consider turning off these values:

```
dnssec-enable yes;
dnssec-validation auto;
dnssec-lookaside . trust-anchor dlv.isc.org.;
```